# Publishing .net application

Tags: .net, publishing

I've created .net application, and now I'm trying to publish this application on another computer. So, on solution properties Target framweork is 4.5. After that I publish this application an now I'm trying to install this app.
So, when I run installation I get "... has stopped working error".
Details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: test.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 534ac6de
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa57ca
  Problem Signature 07: 43c1
  Problem Signature 08: 1b0
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1062
  Additional Information 1: d876
  Additional Information 2: d87651cd8e4629eb7a10f0dc719205b2
  Additional Information 3: 1df2
  Additional Information 4: 1df208746514c75dadfcc544227e67c3
```

Where can be problem? Thanks.

Comment: 1. how do you make installer?
2. is .NET framework 4.5 present on target computer?

Comment: 1. Right click on solution / Publish... 2. Yes. 3. Another thing - When I run this installer on computer were I develope this app, I get some error, but when I run app from Visual studio all works great.

Comment: Are you loading and assemblies manually (i.e. at runtime via reflection).  If that doesn't make sense, the answer is no :)

Comment: No I don't load assemblies via reflection...